# ¿Cómo puedo encontrar todos los registros coincidentes del store en ExtJS?

Tags: extjs

<sub>Basándome en la pregunta [Extjs store find all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511588/extjs-store-find-all) sin respuesta aceptada formulo aquí la misma, con la esperanza de que podamos darle una solución.</sub>

En la [documentación](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#method-find) de Sencha dice:

> Finds the index of the first matching Record in this store by a specific field value.

es decir:

> Encuentra el índice del primer Record en la store que coincide con algún valor de campo.

Mi pregunta es, ¿cómo puedo encontrar **todos** los registros coincidentes del store?

Estoy usando ExtJS6.

Answer (score 0):

Nunca he usado `ExtJS`, y de Javascript no es que vaya muy *sobrao* que digamos, pero se me ocurre algo tal que así:

```
Ext.Data.AbstractStore.prototype.findAllExact = function( fieldName, value, index ) {
  var ret = [ ];

  index = index || 0;

  while( ( index = this.findExact( fieldName, value, index ) ) !== -1 ) {
    ret.push( index );

  return ret;
}
```

En la documentación no lo indica (o yo no lo he visto), pero he supuesto que `findExact( )` devuelve **`-1`** si no encuentra ninguna coincidencia.

El código de arriba *debería* de devolver un *array* con los índices de todos los elementos coincidentes.